# GIT deployment using Bitbucket SSH deployment key and post hook

Tags: git, hook, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I have a Bitbucket repo and 5 servers to which I want to clone it. My plan was to create a deployment key and apply it to each server and then use a post hook call a deployment script to do a pull and ease the changes into place. I need the key as it's a private repo.

However, web processes and therefore the post hook would be executed as apache, and for security apache is a "no login" user, so I can't login to the server as or su to apache, so am not seeing a way to create and store the SSH key.

Any suggestions would be welcome. Am I overthinking this? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: ssh key is stored in home directory of user, isn't it?

Comment: Normally, yes. But as this is a no-login user, it doesn't have one.

Comment: hm,apache is launched from user www-data by default.  This is not real user,so you can't store keys for it. As solution you can login using existing/or a new one (i.e. human) account and store key using ssh-copy-id. Is it possible?